# Проблема с кодировкой windows-1251 на linux

Tags: java, linux, кодировка, groovy

Читаю *txt*-файлы в *java/groovy* в кодировке *WINDOWS-1251*.

Часть файлов читается успешно, но один файл из *1С* читается успешно только под *windows*, а под *linux* кодировка обрабатывается неверно.

Код чтения из файла *Groovy*

```
  String fileEncoding = "cp1251"
  file.eachLine(fileEncoding) { line -> esvData << line.split('=')
    System.out.println(line)}
```

В логе на *Windows* видны русские буквы, а на *i686-redhat-linux(6.0)* лог имеет следующий вид:

> 1CClientBankExchange
>   Р’РµСЂСЃРёСЏР¤РѕСЂРјР°С‚Р°=1.02
>   РљРѕРґРёСЂРѕРІРєР°=Windows
>   РћС‚РїСЂР°РІРёС‚РµР»СЊ=
>   РџРѕР»СѓС‡Р°С‚РµР»СЊ=
>   Р”Р°С‚Р°РЎРѕР·РґР°РЅРёСЏ=23.03.2015
>   Р’СЂРµРјСЏРЎРѕР·РґР°РЅРёСЏ=01:46:15
>   Р”Р°С‚Р°РќР°С‡Р°Р»Р°=20.03.2015
>   Р”Р°С‚Р°РљРѕРЅС†Р°=20.03.2015
>   Р Р°СЃС‡РЎС‡РµС‚=407028

При этом файлы в кодировке *windows-1251* из других источников обрабатываются успешно на том же *linux*.

В чем-то, кроме кодировки, может быть разница? Слышал, что могут присутствовать какие-то доп. символы в начале файла.

```
package com.peterservice.pays.filepay.camel.processors.inscriptproc;

import com.peterservice.pays.filepay.camel.processors.InScriptProc;
import com.peterservice.pays.filepay.enums.CamelProperties;
import com.peterservice.pays.filepay.enums.Directories;
import com.peterservice.pays.filepay.model.Pay;
import com.peterservice.pays.filepay.model.PayRoute;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchange;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by Yuriy.Vinogradov on 06.08.2015.
 */
public class InScriptProc1CTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        InScriptProc processor = new InScriptProc();
        Exchange exchange = prepareExchange();
        processor.process(exchange);
        Pay[] payments = exchange.getIn().getBody(Pay[].class);
        Assert.assertEquals(256, payments.length);
        for (Pay payment : payments) {
            if (payment.number.equals("549")) {
                Assert.assertEquals(new BigDecimal("0.4"), payment.amount);
                Assert.assertEquals("2015-03-20", payment.inDate);
                Assert.assertEquals("770fgh320", payment.INN);
                Assert.assertEquals("770fhh001", payment.payerKpp);
                Assert.assertEquals("401058fgh000fh79", payment.payerAccount);
                Assert.assertEquals("УФК по г.Москве (ФКУ \"Дирекция космодрома \"Восточный\")", payment.payerTitle);
                Assert.assertEquals("25904fgh2221 0373fg910 Опл.  за услуги сот.связи за декабрь2014, дог.от 12.12.14  №2350948, сч.14-1 от 26.12.2014, акт  DV03/70761371/28  от 26,12,2014 , в т.ч. НДС-0,06 (л/с 15fg925)", payment.paymentReason);
            } else if(payment.number.equals("701")) {
                Assert.assertEquals(new BigDecimal("1.79"), payment.amount);
                Assert.assertEquals("2015-03-20", payment.inDate);
                Assert.assertEquals("2815fff915", payment.INN);
                Assert.assertEquals("27fff1001", payment.payerKpp);
                Assert.assertEquals("30302810fffh0000100", payment.payerAccount);
                Assert.assertEquals("ФКП \"Аэропорты Дальнего Востока\" р/с 40502810409fghfh001 в ХФ ОАО \"МДМ БАНК\"  г Хабаровск", payment.payerTitle);
                Assert.assertEquals("УИНО///Оплата по сч-фак. №10010687719/800 от 28.02.2015 л/счет 1fgh4543. Сумма 1-79 В т.ч. НДС  (18%) 0-27", payment.paymentReason);
            } else if(payment.number.equals("822")) {
                Assert.assertEquals(new BigDecimal("50"), payment.amount);
            }else{
           //     Assert.fail("Not expected document number:" + payment.number + " Check if it is correct and create if branch for this document number");
            }
        } 
    }

    private Exchange prepareExchange() {
        Exchange exchange = new DefaultExchange(new DefaultCamelContext());
        PayRoute payRoute = new PayRoute();
        exchange.getIn().setBody(payRoute);
        payRoute.setInScript("src/scripts/1c-java.groovy");
        Map<String, String> resultDirs = new HashMap<>();
        resultDirs.put(Directories.ERROR.title, "test/" + Directories.ERROR.title + "/dir/");
        resultDirs.put(Directories.GF.title, "test/" + Directories.GF.title + "/dir/");
        resultDirs.put(Directories.LG.title, "test/" + Directories.LG.title + "/dir/");
        resultDirs.put(Directories.UNDEFINED.title, "test/" + Directories.GF.title + "/dir/");
        resultDirs.put(Directories.LOG.title, "test/" + Directories.LOG.title + "/dir/");
        payRoute.setResultDirs(resultDirs);
        exchange.setProperty(CamelProperties.ProcessingFile.title, new File("src/test/resources/sberbank_27_20150320_1.txt").getAbsoluteFile());
        return exchange;
    }
}
```

hexdump  для проверки начала файла на bom

```
[relstand@srv3-amain-a test]$ hexdump -C sberbank_27_20150320_1.txt | head
00000000  31 43 43 6c 69 65 6e 74  42 61 6e 6b 45 78 63 68  |1CClientBankExch|
00000010  61 6e 67 65 0d 0a c2 e5  f0 f1 e8 ff d4 ee f0 ec  |ange............|
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

вы применили лишнюю перекодировку «из cp1251 в utf8», в чём несложно убедиться, выполнив обратную перекодировку:

```
$ echo '1CClientBankExchange Р’РµСЂСЃРёСЏР¤РѕСЂРјР°С‚Р°=1.02 РљРѕРґРёСЂРѕРІРєР°' | iconv -f utf8 -t cp1251
1CClientBankExchange ВерсияФормата=1.02 Кодировка
```

читайте этот файл «как есть», без каких-либо перекодировок.

> Слышал, что могут присутствовать какие-то доп символы в начале файла?

да, это называется [*bom*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2). убедиться в их наличии/остутствии можно, например, так:

```
$ hexdump -C путь.к.исследуемому.файлу | head
00000000  70 61 63 6b 61 67 65 20  63 6f 6d 2e 70 65 74 65  |package com.pete|
00000010  72 73 65 72 76 69 63 65  2e 70 61 79 73 2e 66 69  |rservice.pays.fi|
00000020  6c 65 70 61 79 2e 63 61  6d 65 6c 2e 70 72 6f 63  |lepay.camel.proc|
00000030  65 73 73 6f 72 73 2e 69  6e 73 63 72 69 70 74 70  |essors.inscriptp|
00000040  72 6f 63 3b 0a 0a 69 6d  70 6f 72 74 20 63 6f 6d  |roc;..import com|
00000050  2e 70 65 74 65 72 73 65  72 76 69 63 65 2e 70 61  |.peterservice.pa|
00000060  79 73 2e 66 69 6c 65 70  61 79 2e 63 61 6d 65 6c  |ys.filepay.camel|
00000070  2e 70 72 6f 63 65 73 73  6f 72 73 2e 49 6e 53 63  |.processors.InSc|
00000080  72 69 70 74 50 72 6f 63  3b 0a 69 6d 70 6f 72 74  |riptProc;.import|
00000090  20 63 6f 6d 2e 70 65 74  65 72 73 65 72 76 69 63  | com.peterservic|
```

---

**обновление**

а ещё парсер, теоретически, может «сбиваться» из-за разных [окончаний строк](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8).

распространённых вариантов как минимум три:

- cr
- lf
- cr + lf

для изменения этих символов в операционной системе *gnu/linux* можно воспользоваться программами (из пакета *dos2unix*, присутствующего в репозиториях всех популярных дистрибутивов):

- dos2unix
- unix2dos
- unix2mac
- mac2unix

вызов (для замены пары `cr + lf` на `lf`):

```
$ dos2unix путь.к.файлу
```

Comment: Я этой перекодировки не делаю, интересно, где она может происходить, при коммите в git?

Comment: я опираюсь на информацию из вашего вопроса. у меня же нет доступа к самому файлу, только к опубликованному вами логу. посмотрите, что находится в самом файле, а не в логе. например, с помощью приведённой мною команды. а вывод её приложите к вопросу (в комментариях форматированный вывод, увы, нечитабелен).

Comment: @YuriyVinogradov, я дополнил ответ информацией про переводы строк.

Comment: Спасибо. hexdump привел.

Comment: @YuriyVinogradov, то, что вы добавили, совсем не похоже на вывод команды `hexdump -C какой-нибудь.файл | head`. я добавил пример вывода команды в свой ответ. это первый из приведённыйх вами листингов, сохранённый в файл.

Comment: @YuriyVinogradov Вы пометили ответ как решение, значит проблему удалось решить? Что в итоге было?

Comment: @MikhailBatcer, возможно, автор по ошибке нажал на «галочку». хотя отметка «галочкой» означает буквально: «принят **данный** ответ». трактовать это как решение или не трактовать — зависит от «трактующего».

Comment: Пока решение не найдено. В результате консультаций было выяснено, что программа будет запускаться по Windows, поэтому вопрос пока можно отложить. Под Windows эта ошибка не возникает. 
У меня пока не хватает репутации лайкать, поэтому я ваш ответ отметил галочкой, как наиболее полный. 
Также, я понял, что проблема может быть не в кодировке, потому что, как написал Mikhail Batcer, вероятно это консоль портит кодировку при выводе. Я не могу предположить на данный момент в чем причина ошибки. Я использовал аналог hexdump для windows - filehdr.exe, поэтому формат вывода отличается.

Comment: В итоге перевел код из groovy в java с изменениями только синтаксиса и проблема ушла. Причина от этого яснее не стала.

Answer (score 4):

Это не win-1251. Так выглядит Юникод, ошибочно принятый за win-1251.

Вот вам картинка-подсказка по распознаванию кодировок: https://hsto.org/files/d77/1c6/054/d771c60540c44bc984641c337fd099f0.png

Comment: Если я ставлю unicode, получаются иероглифы
При utf-8 получаются квадраты с вопросами. Под windows успешно обрабатывается, только если установить кодировку win-1251

Comment: там просто битый юникод. Видимо его кто то уже пытался пару раз преобразовать и неудачно.

Comment: А может, проблема в кодировке консоли на Linux?

Comment: Прогоняется java тест и он валится на linux, но отрабатывает успешно на windows.

Comment: @YuriyVinogradov Добавьте, пожалуйста, к вопросу код теста.

Comment: добавил код теста и скрипта

Comment: @YuriyVinogradov Спасибо, а известно, где в тесте возникает ошибка?

Comment: Скрипт разбора файла не может его правильно распарсить, поэтому возвращает пустой массив платежей. Распарсить не может, как я понял из печати результатов чтения файла в консоль, которые привел выше, потому что неверно понимает кодировку.

Comment: @YuriyVinogradov *Скрипт разбора файла не может его правильно распарсить* — нет ли проблемы с окончаниями строк? приложите, всё-таки, к вопросу вывод команды, которую я привёл в своём ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Сработала команда: gsettings set org.x.editor.preferences.encodings auto-detected "['UTF-8', 'WINDOWS-1251', 'KOI8-R', 'CP866', 'CURRENT', 'ISO-8859-15', 'UTF-16']"

Система: Linux Mint 19.3 XFCE